# How do I remove an entire row if more than 60% or more of columns after a specific column contains the same specific value?

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed

I have a very large tab separated file formated like below (with roughly 300 columns and 1.2 million rows). The columns are all formated the same after column 4 (just with different numbers, but are all formated with `#/#` or `./.`)

`The headings seem to be to long resulting in a bit of shifted look`

```
CHROM   POS     REF     ALT     LarsenP1_1_PI173627.sort        LarsenP1_1_PI173630.sort        LarsenP1_1_PI204384.sort        LarsenP1_1_PI204386.sort        LarsenP1_1_PI204550.sort
1J_LG1  393466  A       [C]     ./.     1/2     1/1     0/0     0/1     
1J_LG1  393472  G       [A, C]  5/6     ./.     ./.     1/0     0/0         
1J_LG1  393475  G       [A]     ./.     ./.     ./.     ./.     ./.     
1J_LG1  393482  T       [C]     0/0     1/1     1/2     2/2     ./.
1J_LG1  393762  A       [C]     0/0     ./.     ./.     2/2     ./.
```

I am trying to remove all rows with the values `./.` in 60% or more of every column after column 4 (not including column 4, so column 5 and onward). Essentially in the example above rows 3 and 5 would be removed. It should produce an output as seen below.

```
CHROM   POS     REF     ALT     LarsenP1_1_PI173627.sort        LarsenP1_1_PI173630.sort        LarsenP1_1_PI204384.sort        LarsenP1_1_PI204386.sort        LarsenP1_1_PI204550.sort
1J_LG1  393466  A       [C]     ./.     1/2     1/1     0/0     0/1
1J_LG1  393472  G       [A, C]  5/6     ./.     ./.     1/0     0/0
1J_LG1  393482  T       [C]     0/0     ./.     ./.     2/2     ./.
```

I am very new to programming and bioinformatics and would really appreciate the help. From doing some research I think that I should be using something like `awk` or `sed`, but I'm not sure.

Also I'm sorry if the formatting isn't great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `./.` and `0/0` only ever appear in the fields after #4 and are always a full field, all you need is:

```
$ awk -F'\t' 'gsub(/\.\/\./,"&") < ((NF-4)*.6)' file
CHROM   POS     REF     ALT     LarsenP1_1_PI173627.sort        LarsenP1_1_PI173630.sort        LarsenP1_1_PI204384.sort        LarsenP1_1_PI204386.sort     LarsenP1_1_PI204550.sort
1J_LG1  393466  A       [C]     ./.     1/2     1/1     0/0     0/1
1J_LG1  393472  G       [A, C]  5/6     ./.     ./.     1/0     0/0
1J_LG1  393482  T       [C]     0/0     1/1     1/2     2/2     ./.

$ awk -F'\t' 'gsub(/\.\/\.|0\/0/,"&") < ((NF-4)*.6)' file
CHROM   POS     REF     ALT     LarsenP1_1_PI173627.sort        LarsenP1_1_PI173630.sort        LarsenP1_1_PI204384.sort        LarsenP1_1_PI204386.sort     LarsenP1_1_PI204550.sort
1J_LG1  393466  A       [C]     ./.     1/2     1/1     0/0     0/1
1J_LG1  393482  T       [C]     0/0     1/1     1/2     2/2     ./.
```

Comment: After reviewing both output files from the first solution and this one, I noticed that this one produced about 15,000 fewer results. I looked at the files in more detail and it seems this solution is more accurate then the first one (the first solution missed some lines). Thanks! :)

Comment: That's surprising. I'd have expected this solution to be much faster than the other one but to produce the same results. Oh well. You're welcome!

Answer (score 1):

***1st solution:*** Could you please try following.

```
awk '{for(i=5;i<=NF;i++){val=$i;sum+=sub(/\.\/\./,"",val)};if((sum/(NF-4))*100<60){print};sum=""}'   Input_file
```

OR(adding a non-one liner form of above solution)

```
awk '
{
  for(i=5;i<=NF;i++){
    val=$i
    sum+=sub(/\.\/\./,"",val)
  }
  if((sum/(NF-4))*100<60){
    print
  }
  sum=""
}'  Input_file
```

***2nd Solution:*** Or this could be more fast(though haven't checked on millions of lines).

```
awk '{for(i=5;i<=NF;i++){if($i ~ /^\.\/\.$/){sum++}};if((sum/(NF-4))*100<60){print};sum=""}'  Input_file
```

OR(a non-one liner form of above solution):

```
awk '
{
  for(i=5;i<=NF;i++){
    if($i ~ /^\.\/\.$/){
      sum++
    }
  }
  if((sum/(NF-4))*100<60){
      print
  }
  sum=""
}'   Input_file
```

In case you have TAB delimited data then change `awk` to `awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"}....` in above codes too.

Comment: Awesome! The first solution I tested seems to worked perfectly. Just out of curiousity, if I wanted to modify the script to also include `0/0` and `./.`. In other words to remove all rows that contain `./.` or `0/0` in 60% or more of every column after column 4, how would I do that? So this would result in the removal of row 2 in the initial example.

Comment: @D.Nedaie, IMHO 2nd solution should be more fast between 2 of them try changing `$i ~ /^\.\/\.$/` TO `$i ~ /^\.\/\.$/ || $i ~ /0\/0/` in 2nd solution. Try changing `sum+=sub(/\.\/\./,"",val)` TO `sum+=gsub(/\.\/\.|/0\/0//,"",val)` in 1st solution and let me know then,how it goes.

Comment: Thanks again, the modification to the second solution works, however the modification to the first solution didn't (syntax error on one of the backslashes between the zeros). Thanks again, I will use the second solution, it was noticeably faster as well.